# how show echo only once in foreach and if else if condition

Tags: php, json, loops, if-statement, foreach

here is my json data

> {    "order_id":"#BCB28FB2",    "salutation":"Mr",    "name":"Testing
> Data",    "cart":[
> {
> "id":13,
> "name":"tes1",
> "treatment_type":"tes",
> },
> {
> "id":14,
> "name":"tes2",
> "treatment_type":"tes",
> },
> {
> "id":15,
> "name":"Panel",
> "treatment_type":"panel",
> },
> {
> "id":16,
> "name":"Paket",
> "treatment_type":"paket",
> },    ] }

and this my code

```
foreach($data['cart'] as $value){
   if($value['treatment_type'] == 'tes'){
      echo "Its a tes<br>";
   }
   elseif($value['treatment_type'] == 'panel'){
      echo "Its a panel<br>";
   }else{
      echo "Its a paket<br>";
   }
}
```

my site showing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs5tI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kTLo.png)
how to show like this

Comment: In your json you have numerous tes items. That is why there are multiple prints.

Comment: how can i output echo only once though i have numerous tes items ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use `array_unique` to do the job

- put all $value['treatment_type'] into a temp array
- apply array_unique on it

So the code is

```
<?php

$json='{ "order_id":"#BCB28FB2", "salutation":"Mr", "name":"Testing Data", "cart":[ { "id":13, "name":"tes1", "treatment_type":"tes" }, { "id":14, "name":"tes2", "treatment_type":"tes" }, { "id":15, "name":"Panel", "treatment_type":"panel" }, { "id":16, "name":"Paket", "treatment_type":"paket" } ] }';

$data=json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data['cart'] as $value){
   $data2[]=$value['treatment_type'];
}

$data3=array_unique($data2);

foreach($data3 as $value){

   if($value == 'tes'){
      echo "Its a tes<br>";
   }
   elseif($value == 'panel'){
      echo "Its a panel<br>";
   }else{
      echo "Its a paket<br>";
   }
}
?>
```

Actually for the foreach loop, you may further simplify to the following:

```
foreach($data3 as $value){
  echo "Its a " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

You may check the execution result at the following sandbox URL:

https://onlinephp.io/c/f503c